# How to handle with url which contains spaces in Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, static-files

When I want to display some images in Flask, I use `url_for` to link on image.

Problem is when path to the image contains spaces. Spaces in URL are transformed to `%20` and file cannot be displayed because image throws for example

> GET http://localhost:5000/static/user_files/e54fd12w5r47e8f4/50%20File%20Type%20Vector%20Icons/PNG/dll.png 404 (NOT FOUND)

I tried to rename folder to name without spaces and it works.

Comment: Show the name of the file with `ls -alh` and also show the route you have used for static route

Comment: @TarunLalwani There is nothing wrong with file name. Problem is with folder name.

Comment: I meant need to check folder name and the route code you have used for static files

Comment: @TarunLalwani
`ls -alh` is `drwxrwxr-x 3 hanis hanis 4,0K zář  1 14:00 50 File Type Vector Icons`
And i dont have any route to display files. I use just `url_for` to link to files
`{{ url_for('static', filename=file.path) }}`

Comment: I am not asking about templates. To serve static files in Flask, you need to create a route or configure static files. There are multiple ways to do it. How have you done that? I want to understand that

Comment: I'm using [Flask-Skeleton](https://github.com/realpython/flask-skeleton), I'm not sure how is it done there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153478/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-honza-sedlo).